# Only One "Global" variable - Implementing Correctly?

Tags: php

I reduced my globals to only one.  Seems a bit weird to inject a class with only one variable and a getter function, but I don't want any implicit dependencies, I want them all explicit and documented.  Also I only want the "globals" accessible to the classes I give access to.  So in a sense they are not global.  Need to re-name to shared.  LOAD_ON is the only variable that I need in multiple classes.

Is this the correct way (best practice) to implement a "global" variable when trying to adhere to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) / DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) / OOP ( Object Oriented Programming).

```
<?php 

class GlobalClass
{
    private $LOAD_ON = 0;
    public function getLoad()
    {
        return $this->LOAD_ON;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you use something like the registry design pattern to workaround using $GLOBALS?

Comment: The answer here points that this is in the correct direction -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151341/registry-design-pattern-good-or-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got only 1 'global' and don't need to change it, constants are the best practice.

```
define('LOAD_ON', 0);
```

Use it in this way

```
if(LOAD_ON === 0){
 ///...
```

Comment: Yes, and so is your class. I could just use $gc = new GlobalClass();

Comment: Registry pattern provides encapsulation...so now it will be new Shared();...where Shared implement this pattern....0 Globals...may seem over-engineered...but for consistency I'm going to use it.